# How to do something after browser did all render actions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have big form. This form works on really old PC`s. This form is a part of some thin client. I use AngularJS to implement SPA and on of the tabs is this form.

When I open form I send some requests to backend and get some data. After it, based on this answers, AngularJS (by `ngIf` and `ngShow` directives build form).

Lifecycle is:
1) get permissions and get data
2) render *some* fields (based on permissions) with this data

There are about 150 fields on the form. Well it takes a while, when browser renders about 80-100 components. Well this is not problem in this post...

I have some glass pane on my form. When form is not ready glass pane must be shown above the form. The problem is I can handle the glass pane just on some actions. I do this:

1. enable glass pane
2. start data and permissions api requests
3. get data and permissions api requests answer
4. disable glass pane
5. **render fields based on permissions**

The problem is browser rendering fields after glass pane was disabled.

How I can disable glass pane after browser finished rendering dom?

The code is:

```
makePermissionsRequest().then(function (permissionsModel) {
  $scope.permissionsModel = permissionsModel;
});
```

Comment: Some code might help.

Comment: You are thinking about this all wrong.  Angular doesn't *directly* **respond** to Rendering events in the browser.  Angular uses a cycle (`$digest`) where it checks to see if the value of any JavaScript properties it knows about have changed, and re-renders the DOM. It *sounds like* what you want to do is enable the glass pane when your page is loaded, and disable it in response to your data (in the `.then()` callback).  just using `ng-if` or `ng-show` to monitor a Boolean should serve for this purpose.

Comment: @Claies Ty for your answer. Seems to me I have really bad english :) You totally misunderstood me. I understand perfectly what $digest cycle is and I understand that when I got responses, $digest works, watches ngIf/ngShow directives and then AngularJS changes dom. At this point browser starts to render the dom. I need to somehow disable glass pane after this render.

Comment: Ty for your answer @DanWilson. I added some code.

Comment: if you are concerned about the rendering cycle, then you are trying to do something that angular won't be responsible for.  I'm sure there are other frameworks or pure JavaScript that can handle the task, but you aren't "thinking in angular" if you feel like this is necessary for your app, and it isn't something that angular developers would recommend.

Comment: I'm confused about what you want and what you don't want. What is it that you desire to have happen, and what is an error?

Comment: Well when I started this application I didn't think I will code my app using somethink like "renderready" events :D First time everything was ok, but now there are really many components on this form. I am trying to optimize it and it works (for example browser was freezing for 5 seconds, now it is freezing only for 1-2 seconds). But I can't remove thi s freeze at all, thats why I am looking for these ways to show user that browser is working.

Comment: @activedecay Desire what I want: i want to disable glass pane after page is rendered and painted (after AngularJS updated DOM). What I don't want: I don't want glass pane to be disabled before browser rendered and painted all components of the form.

Comment: Do you mean that digest cycle runs for 1-2 sec? Then some workaround can be found only outside angular.

Comment: Chrome DevTools shows that this digest works for 800ms, but IE is not as fast as Chrome... And yes. Question is not about how to optimize this digest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a mutation observer to do your desired code

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    // disable the glass pane because the form was mutated
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

var target = ... // angular.element("yourform") would give you the form node

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```